# List is empty after linq operation

Tags: c#, linq

I have problem to understend what is happening in foreach loop- listOfBookedTimes successfuly gets elements that I want, but after execution of the next line listOfBookedTimes is empty. Why? (All lists contain DateTime)

```
  foreach (var day in allDays)
        {
            list = Rep.GetListOfWorkingHours(fullDayWorkingHours, day, sPWorkingHours);
            bookedTimes = _bookingsService.GetBookedTimes(day, providerId);
            foreach (var b in bookedTimes)
            {
                var listOfBookedTimes = list.Where(m => m.TimeOfDay == (b.TimeOfAppointment.TimeOfDay));
                list.RemoveAll(m => m.TimeOfDay == (b.TimeOfAppointment.TimeOfDay));
                listOfBookedTimes.Select(m => m.Year - 50);
                list.AddRange(listOfBookedTimes); 
            }
```

Comment: you're removing all `listOfBookedTimes` from `list`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is not the `RemoveAll` but rather the fundemental understanding of LinQ and `yield return.`

When you call

```
list.Where(m => m.TimeOfDay == (b.TimeOfAppointment.TimeOfDay));
```

it is not executed but rather returns an enumerator that will filter the collection on iteration. In the next line you remove all entries you wanted to fetch in the previous line.

When you finally iterate the collection in

```
list.AddRange(listOfBookedTimes);
```

it is already empty.

**Solution:** Add `.ToArray()` or `.ToList()` after the `Where` and it should work as expected. Like this:

```
var listOfBookedItems = list.Where(m => m.TimeOfDay == (b.TimeOfAppointment.TimeOfDay))
                            .ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

You are removing all elements from the list in this statement

```
list.RemoveAll(m => m.TimeOfDay == (b.TimeOfAppointment.TimeOfDay));
```

notice that

`listOfBookedTimes = list.Where(m => m.TimeOfDay == (b.TimeOfAppointment.TimeOfDay));`

and

`list.RemoveAll(m => m.TimeOfDay == (b.TimeOfAppointment.TimeOfDay));`

have the same condition

You can execute `ToList()` in order to get a new copy of the list, so that removing items from the original `list` won't affect it:

```
listOfBookedTimes = list.Where(m => m.TimeOfDay == (b.TimeOfAppointment.TimeOfDay)).ToList();
```

**BUT**

`listOfBookedTimes` still holds the references to the original items from the `list` so while adding removing elements to both those lists won't affect each other, modifying properties of single item that is contained by both lists will be applied to both of them.

Comment: @ Alex Art Yes but I tought that listOfBookedTimes will keep values and only list will be changed